# Un-install 32bit Ubuntu and Install 64bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10

I had a Windows 7 operating system, I then wrote over that OS with Ubuntu 11.10.
This heavily increased my disk space, but since i installed a 32bit version of Ubuntu onto my once 64bit OS my RAM was cut in half.

How exactly do you uninstall the 32bit and install the 64bit when you have no Windows to go back to and no CD-ROM drive?
(I installed Ubuntu with a flash drive)

Answer (score 2):

1. Backup any and all important data.
2. Download the 64bit iso of 12.04.1, check the md5sum is correct (good copy) and use "startup disk creator" to make a LiveUSB
3. Boot off the LiveUSB and start the installation of Ubuntu
4. When prompted, just select "use all of the disk"

This should be almost exactly the same procedure you used to replace Windows (congratulations on that, by the way ;-)

Comment: I did the same thing, but when i boot from usb i just get a blank black screen and it never does anything.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to set nomodeset when you boot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it.  You did check the md5sum for the new iso, right?